# What is the reason for ORA-00054 error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00054

From Oracle's documentation:-

```
ORA-00054 resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified   

  Cause: Resource interested is busy.
  Action: Retry if necessary.
```

In our code we issue a `SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` command to lock the row we are about to update.

Right now the logic is if it returns SQL error `54` then it is assumed that another user is trying to update that same record. Is this logic valid?

From Oracle's documentation it looks more like if the DB is overwhelmed then this might also cause this error to be thrown.

What are the possible reasons for this error, when we are only using the above SQL command?

Comment: Does the error return immediately, or as a timeout?

Comment: I cannot debug or put sops there, so I am not sure if it returns immediately. The code is running in a standalone server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SELECT ... FOR UPDATE attempts to acquire an RS (Row Share) lock on the table and an X (eXclusive) lock on the row. If another session has an exclusive lock on the table (eg creating an index) or an exclusive lock on the row (update, delete, or select for update) then the query will wait for the other transaction to release the lock (commit or rollback generally) unless you have specified NOWAIT.

So one possibility is to not specify NOWAIT.

I don't recognise the situation where the database might throw this error due to being "overwhelmed".

Comment: That is the problem here. This is my local database and I am the only user. Is there any way to find it form the db which user had locked that row causing this error?

Comment: Oops my last comment wasn't clear. Is there a way to find from the db which user and what query had locked that row causing this error?

Comment: If you modify the query to WAIT then the system view DBA_WAITERS should help you identify the locking session.

Comment: yes, if you try to do an update on that row, you can see who is blocking you. v$lock, v$session and other views...

Comment: @AppleGrew, check out this page for how to identify a blocking lock: http://www.orafaq.com/node/854

Comment: There is yet another reason. This is what hit us. Oracle loads data in blocks, each has some no. of rows. Which row is locked is registered in block header. Sometimes the no. of slots in register could be less than the no. or rows in the block. When the slots are exhausted so additional request to lock (unlocked) rows in the same block too errors out. After all ORA54 simply means - resource busy.

Comment: Possibly so, though only if you exceed MAXTRANS I'd think. You ought to see a TX enqueue in mode 4, which is a wait event of "enq: TX - allocate ITL entry", if you do suffer from this problem.